# How much food should a polar bear eat?

Tags: dnd-5e, animal-companions

I am running an Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden game with my table, and the players may manage to convince a polar bear or two of joining them. And where I could run with them using the bears in place of sled dogs or axebeaks... I do wish to tax them for having them around.

By the DMG, the bears would eat 4 lbs of meat a day, and if I was to go by rations cost, this would mean each bear would consume 2 GP worth of rations per day.

Does this feel like too little? Like too much?

Comment: Feel is very subjective, which isn't a good fit for a Stack question. If you want to know how much food a real polar bear eats in a day, I'm sure that information is available on a nature website or some such thing (and I'm sure it varies depending on the time of year), which might give you a better feel for the realism of it.  4 lbs sounds low to me, but I haven't done even basic research.

Comment: I think there could be a good question in here, but we'd need a clearer idea of what your concern is? Too much or too little on what scale? Realism? Taxing a PC? We might also need other, relevant details depending on the need, and it's possible this won't work here regardless (in which case you may be better served by a traditional [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### As much as you think is right

This is spelled on p.6 of the PHB “The DM narrates the result of the character’s actions” - if they give it enough food, all is good, if they don’t, it eats *them*.

There are [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#FoodandWater) for how much food a character needs (1 lb. a day) but there are no rules for how much a polar bear needs. It makes no difference if the character is small or medium.

Is it reasonable that a polar bear needs more? Sure. How much more? It depends on the requirements of your game.

Humans eat regularly, several times a day. Polar bears [don’t](https://seaworld.org/animals/all-about/polar-bear/diet/) - they eat a seal entirely about once a week. That averages to about 15 lb. a day but that isn’t a sensible number. It’s like saying the average human has about one testicle and one ovary, technically correct but not very informative.

However, this introduces a further problem - humans don’t eat 1 lb. of food a day. In the United States, the [average](https://news.yahoo.com/much-humans-eat-numerical-breakdown-181300224.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS5hdS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAKplsdw7-Oqi6r2oXQcZGes160dP-mkjmzb6uXm4GCy8HKDebx2qfAhNEKUWet0aLFgErKZatbw2iu0kmp_6Hc2MaUg50ylOJy0Ctag_UIIc4DvRp52BfmV53xsct9-LDsSSX1qWgux5D_k7iqYPMWAlcCQHRZCIbPuCtPdNSbSo) is about 5.5 lb. a day, not 1 lb. Further, the *quantity* eaten tells us noting about the actual important stuff - how many calories and nutrients are eaten. US diets are *extreemly* calorie rich - unless you are an elite athlete, 5.5 lb. is *way* too much food, probably 10-20% too much.

The game makes no distinction between high calorie/nutrient density foods and low. A pound of celery is equivalent to a pound of lard within the rules of the game. This is one of the abstractions that make the game a game and not a life simulator.

So, you tell me, is 4 lb. a day reasonable?